# Multiline PHP Regex problem

Tags: php, regex, multiline

I already tried looking here and in google... but I can't figure out what am I doing wrong :(

I have this text:

```
C 1 title
comment 1

C 2 title2
comment 2

C 3 title3
comment 3
```

Now... What I want to do is

1. Check for the C at the beggining.
2. Capture the number
3. Capture the Tile
4. Capture the comment

I'm trying to use this expression:

```
preg_match_all("/^C (\d*) (.*)\n(.*)$/im", $body, $match);
```

but it only works for the first set =(

Any tip on what am I doing wrong???

Thanks!!!!

Comment: try this

    `^C\s\d\s\w+\r\w+`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works as expected.

The snippet:

```
<?php
$body = 'C 1 title
comment 1

C 2 title2
comment 2

C 3 title3
comment 3';

preg_match_all("/^C (\d*) (.*)\n(.*)$/im", $body, $match);

print_r($match);
?>
```

produces the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => C 1 title
comment 1
            [1] => C 2 title2
comment 2
            [2] => C 3 title3
comment 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => title
            [1] => title2
            [2] => title3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => comment 1
            [1] => comment 2
            [2] => comment 3
        )

)
```

as you can see on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Yml9j).

To keep your matches nicely grouped, you might want to try:

```
preg_match_all("/^C (\d*) (.*)\n(.*)$/im", $body, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

instead.

HTH

### EDIT

Ideone runs: `PHP Version => 5.2.12-pl0-gentoo`

And I also tested it on my machine (and get the same result), which runs: `PHP Version => 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5`

But I can't imagine this is a versioning thing (at least, not with 5.x versions). Perhaps your line breaks are Windows style? Try this regex instead:

```
"/^C +(\d*) +(.*)\r?\n(.*)$/im"
```

I used the line break `\r?\n` instead of just `\n` so that Windows and Unix-style line breaks are matched, and also replaced single spaces with `+` to account for possible two (or more) spaces.

Comment: O_O DON'T tell me that... i've been rewriting that expression for 5 hours!!! :S, so.. if it doesn't work... then... is it the server??, PHP 5.1.6... oh my... this is bad :( my print_r only show me the first set :(

Comment: yay, it works!... also... I'm reading the text from a POP server... and I send the text from gmail... this time i sent it using Plain Text... could that be a problem too?? thanks!!!

Comment: @figus, maybe, but I can't tell for sure. Anyway, good to hear it works!